# Arrange the elements optimally for minimum wastage of space

Tags: javascript, html, css, sorting, layout

I am trying to show a list of items such that the space is optimally utilized. As you can see here that the way the elements are arranged is not optimal. There is a lot of space being wasted. Is there any JavaScript library which automatically sorts a list of elements such that minimum space is wasted.

I am currently sorting the elements based on the length of words and then placing them. BTW i am using Tailwind CSS if there is any plugin please mention.

[image: mobile phone layout image]

Comment: `the way the elements are arranged is not optimal` it’s optimal if you are searching for a phrase alphabetically.  If you rearrange the phrases they might be harder for a user to locate.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.